# Removing duplicates with specific conditions

Tags: excel, duplicates

Column B has computer names, some cells have duplicates. Column G shows how many days that computer in the row has been offline. I need to remove the duplicates with the highest day's offline. So for example there could be in column B computer name

```
Computer Name       Days offline
Computer1                5      
Computer1                4
Computer1                3
```

I would want keep the row with 3 days offline and remove the others. Another thing is that not all duplicates have the same amount of duplicate names.

The result should be no duplicates and the days offline should be the lowest value.

Comment: I believe Excel's Remove Duplicates button always keeps the top row. So if you sort this spreadsheet by Computer Name (primary) and Days offline (secondary and ascending) and hit that button, you should get what you want.

Comment: Test it on a copy of the data...

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you. Now I just need to figure out how to make xlrd or openpyxl do that lol